# How to exclude one categorical value in facet wrap ggplot r

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-wrap

I got multiple histograms here using facet_wrap, but somehow I still have 'NA' data in categorical variable for facetting. Then, I changed NA to 0, thinking it won't show in the plot again. Yet, 0 then being another value like NA.

This is the code

```
ggplot(dftrai,aes(`12 Income`,fill=`13e Toilet type`,color=`13e Toilet type`))+
  geom_histogram(alpha=(0.3))+#psition = identity as overlapping histogram
  theme(legend.position = "top")+
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("#999999", "#E69F00", "#56B4E9","#FA3910"))+
  scale_color_manual(values=c("#999999", "#E69F00", "#56B4E9","#FA3910"))+
  facet_wrap(~`13e Toilet type`,ncol = 3)
```

And this is the plot result
I want to get rid of '0' chart over there
[ggplot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hjuft.jpg)

Comment: See `help("droplevels")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to filter *Toilet type* not equal to zero before piping into ggplot:

```
library(dplyr)
dftrai %>% 
filter(`13e Toilet type`!="0") %>%  # Filter step here
ggplot(aes(`12 Income`,fill=`13e Toilet type`,color=`13e Toilet type`))+
  geom_histogram(alpha=(0.3))+#psition = identity as overlapping histogram
  theme(legend.position = "top")+
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("#999999", "#E69F00", "#56B4E9","#FA3910"))+
  scale_color_manual(values=c("#999999", "#E69F00", "#56B4E9","#FA3910"))+
  facet_wrap(~`13e Toilet type`,ncol = 3)
```